# AVG offline install

Tags: anti-virus

Is it possible to install AVG antivirus (the free version) offline?

If so where would I go on their site to download that?

Comment: Perhaps more suited to Superuser.com ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be useful for server admin, especially administrators of windows servers, to weed out windows viruses?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your answer is right on their own download page (if you choose to download AVG directly from AVG instead of download.com or another source)

http://free.avg.com/223204

The offline installer is located at

http://free.avg.com/download-file-ins-afe

Comment: Ahhh okay, the problem was that I was on the trial page at
http://www.avg.com/download-trial

Thanks!

Comment: AVG is a little bit "tricky" when it comes to downloading their free version.  You need to read VERY carefully and notice that the buttons change to text links, etc.  Essentially they try very hard to "drive" you to their pay product. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Latest release -Jan -2010 
http://avg.vo.llnwd.net/o25/inst/avg_free_stf_en_90_716a1803.exe

Answer (score 1):

yeah of course you can !

you just need to download the installer , but its size rather large about 134 mb.
visit this link

http://free.avg.com/de-en/download-free-all-product#tba7

anyway, it's recommended you to install it via online since its installer isn't to big (4mb)

thx